# Dagger - Provide same class from separate modules

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

I have some classes which require a specific object to be injected (lets name it `ToInject`).
The problem is that I cannot provide `ToInject` from separate modules:

```
@Module(injects={OneActivity.class})
public class OneActivityModule {
    @Provides
    public ToInject provideToInject(){
        return new ToInject(...)
    }
}

@Module(injects={TwoActivity.class})
public class TwoActivityModule {
    @Provides
    public ToInject provideToInject(){
        return new ToInject(...)
    }
}
```

I get this exception when creating the ObjectGraph:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TwoActivityModule: Duplicate:
    com.example.test.OneActivityModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideToInjectProvidesAdapter[key=com.example.test.ToInject method=com.example.test.OneActivityModule.provideToInject()]
    com.example.test.TwoActivityModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideToInjectProvidesAdapter[key=com.example.test.ToInject method=com.example.test.TwoActivityModule.provideToInject()]
    at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.makeGraph(ObjectGraph.java:187)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.access$000(ObjectGraph.java:138)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph.create(ObjectGraph.java:129)
```

I know that I could move `ToInject` providers to a single module, and use qualifiers to make then unique, but why can't I do it this way? `injects` is specified for each Module, ain't that makes those providers unique also?

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I thought about it, and the real problem is that I want to configure the `ToInject` object based on which Activity gets it. `ToInject` is actiually an abstract class (and the code snippet above uses a "not abstract" class just for the example).

My conclusion is that I should use only one provider for `ToInject`, so I can change the implementation with the change of a single line of code. But I would still need to configure the `ToInject` object based on which Activity get it.

So the main question became that whether this is possible with Dagger, or do I have to pass the configuration to every Activity, and manually set it?

The configuration in this case is an ID (`String`), and the object to configure (`ToInject` in this example) is a fragment that displays an advert banner. I want to separate it from the Activity as much as possible, so I can reuse it in other projects.

Comment: You can call in activity `onCreate` or `onResume` method from `ToInject` with activity id

Comment: I found a solution that saves me from doing that:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the sufficient solution.

This is a library responsible for providing the implementation of the abstract `ToInject`.

```
@Module(library=true)
public class ProviderModule {
    @Provides
    public ToInject provideToInject(){
        return new ToInjectConcrete1();
    }
}
```

And I can create Activity specific modules the way below. As you can see this `ToInject` provider method has a `ToInject` argument, that is actually provided by the library above. After I got it, I can do my further configuration that is specific to my Activity.

```
@Module(injects = OneActivity.class, includes = ProviderModule.class)
public class OneActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("one")
    public ToInject provideToInject(ToInject toInject) {
        toInject.text = "overridden by one";

        return toInject;
    }
}
```

The key was the usage of qualifiers (in this case the `@Named` qualifier).

**Note:**

The origin of my problem was that I assumed provider methods in separate modules (with `injects` defined) are unique. Now I know that `injects` is for compile time verification, and has nothing to do with the uniquness of the providers. Providers with same return type can be made unique with qualifiers (for example `@Named`) just as how I did in this solution.